# Корень в слове "чуткий"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

В словаре Тихонова 1996г. в слове чуткий - корень чу, т суффикс, к суффикс, ий - окончание. Многие онлайн словаре дают такой же разбор. Может, у участников есть другие словари, в который дргой разбор: чут - корень, к суффикс, ий -окончание.

Дело в том, что начало всему дал древнерусский глагол **чути**, в котором выделялся корень **чу-** и формообразующая морфема **-ти**. Существовало образованное от этого глагола краткое причастие чут, образованное с помощью суффикса **-т-** (как от бить -- бит, битый), от которого с помощью суффикса -к- было образовано прилагательное чуткий, а с помощью суффикса   **-ий- --** отвлечённое существительное чутие (в современном употреблении чутьё). Глагол чути, как и причастия чут, чутый, русским языком утрачены, но сохранились в украинском языке: **чути** (слышать, ощущать, чувствовать) и чутий (слышный).

Поскольку причастие утратилось сегодня, логичнее было бы выделять корень чут. 
Поэтому интересно, есть ли какие-н. словари, выделяющие корень чут?

Comment: _Серж: "В словаре Тихонова 1996г. в слове чуткий - корень чу..."_ === Вы в этом уверены?

Comment: @  slava1947,я цитирую по Викисловарю. Там ссылаются на Тихонова, 1996г.

Comment: Думаю, ошибаются. В моём "Словаре-справочнике по русскому языку" Тихонова, изданном в 1997 г., корень -- ЧУТК.

Comment: А вот ЧУ-Т-К-ИЙ  -- это у Ефремовой с Кузнецовой в "Словаре морфем русского языка" (М., 1986).

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, словообразовательные связи доконца еще закончены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Шанский рассказывает](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Chujat-5497.html):

**ЧУЯТЬ**

Искон. Суф. производное (ср. *баять, пиять* в *пиявка*, *ваять* и т. д.) от *чути* «чувствовать». См. *чу, чувство, чутье*.

Ну и смотрим последовательно:

[**ЧУ**](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Chu-5471.html)

> Искон. Восходит к форме 2-го л. ед. ч. аориста от *чути* «слышать». *Чу*
>   буквально — «ты слышал». См. *чувство*. *Чути* — того же корня, что лат.
>   cavēre «смотреть», англосакс. hāwian «созерцать», греч. koeō
>   «замечаю», готск. hausjan «слышать», akouō «слышу» и др. Ср. слышь,
>   внимание!, польск. pozor.

**[ЧУВСТВО](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Chuvstvo-5474.html)**

> Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где *чувство* — суф. производное от *чувъ*
>   «способность чувствовать» > «тот, кто обладает этим», суф. образование
>   (суф. -в-, ср. нрав, гнев и др.) от *чути* «чувствовать, слышать,
>   ощущать, познавать». См. *чу, чуть*.

[**ЧУТЬ**](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Chut-5491.html)

> Искон. Из сущ. *чуть* «ощущение, чувство» (см. *чутье*), суф.
>   производного (ср. *весть, сласть* и др.) от той же основы, что греч.
>   *koeō* «замечаю» и т. д. (см. *чу*). *Чуть* буквально — «еле заметно», далее — «чуть-чуть», «чуток». Ср. *жуть* в значении «очень много».

**ЧУТЬЁ**

> Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. *-ьjе,* ср. *литье, битье* и др.) от
>   страдат. прич. прош. времени *čutъ* глагола *čuti* (см. *чуткий*).
>
> ---

Двое профессиональных филологов, которых я знаю много лет, согласны с Викисловарём.

---

[Помогите разобрать слово *ЧУТКО* по составу](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/190355541)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Как разобрать по составу слово *чуткий*?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/731259-kak-razobrat-po-sostavu-slovo-chutkij.html#answer7195164)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: "-Т-  суффикс причастия"_. === Суффикс причастия "чутый", которого в современном языке нет?

Comment: Битый, мытый, обманутый: *т* - суффикс причастия. И потом - я же цитирую. Ирина Робертовна - соавтор учебников по языку, автор методичек.

Comment: Галина все это я уже видел и читал. Меня интесовал другое: есть ли какой-нибудь словарь выделяющий корень чут? Спор вышел в группе в Одноклассниках. Одна из участниц утверждает, что, по мнению ее знакомого филолога, в слове выделяется корень чут. После множества аргументов ( словари, и тот, на который вы сделали скриншот) она сослалась на какой-то этимологический словарь, навание которого не помнит. Поэтому и спросил, есть ли какие-нибудь словари, которые выделяют корень чут?

Comment: Вон Тихонов то выделяет корень "чу", то "чутк".

Comment: Серж, одно "мнение знакомого филолога" противопоставлено двум другим. У меня нет морфологических словарей. Если остановиться на версии *чут*, то следует дать отставку словам *чуять* и *чувство* - счесть их дальними этимологическими родственниками.